# Which is the compatible Gson version to be used with java 17

Tags: java-17

We were using Gson 2.8.5 with Java 8. Now we moved to java 17 but few issues we see like below

InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.util.Objects() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @481a15ff

Which is the compatible Gson version to be used with java 17.

Moved to Java 17 with Gson 2.8.5

Comment: What exactly are you trying to serialize? Your post sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: [`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html) consists of `static` helper methods. Why does that software even try to get access to the constructor of that class?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with Gson 2.10.1 while upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17. Any help here will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For me has been solved by adding argLine

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.2</version>
<configuration>
<argLine>
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
</argLine>
</configuration>
```

Comment: <argLine>
                        --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
                    </argLine>

fix - such variant works fine

Answer (score 0):

I also had that error message after upgrading to Java 17.

My solution was to replace Gson with Jackson.
That means instead of

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
...
resultarray = gson.fromJson(body, MyObject.class);
```

change your code to

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
resultarray = objectMapper.readValue(body, MyObject.class);
```

Upgrading Gson to its currently latest version 2.10.1 had not helped, the error remained.

The underlying problem / change in Java is this:
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8256358